# What's the meaning of "inner core" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is a passage from an [article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-11321282) on a study that shows involvement in a romantic relationship comes at the cost of close friends:

> Oxford University researchers asked people about their **inner core** of friendships and how this number changed when romance entered the equation.

What does *inner core* in this passage mean? Is this a figurative usage?

Comment: It's just an unusual (only [one result in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22inner+core+of+friendships%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)) variation on [inner circle of friends](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22inner+circle+of+friends%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (56,000 written instances).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this usage a little unfamiliar, but I think it's still quite understandable.

In general, *core* means the very center of something. Or, as defined by [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=core%20meaning),

> **core** *noun*
>   2. the central or most important part of something, in particular

In this context about friendships, I was a little surprised that they quantified the ***inner core*** of friendships, as suggested by the word *number*. (Counting number of your closest friends is something I'm not familiar with.) Anyway, they must mean the ***number of your closest friends***.

According to the quote, the research seems to suggest that this number of closest friends could change when there was romance involved.

Comment: Maybe I should have quoted the paragragh following that as well; the next paragraph says, "They found the *core*, which numbers about five people, dropped by two as a new lover came to dominate daily life."